# Error: Nonnegative width required in format string at (1)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to compile a piece of code with gfortran and it's failing with the following error:

```
Error: Nonnegative width required in format string at (1)
../src/powmes.f90:410.20:
     write(lunit,'(I,E,E,E)') wavenum(k),power(k),nmodes(k),errorexpan(k)

414   if (filepower_fold(1:1) /= '#') then
415      fileout=trim(filepower_fold)//'.waven'
416      if (verbose) write(*,*) 'Output '//trim(fileout)
417      open(file=fileout,form='formatted',status='unknown',unit=lunit,err=2)
418      do k=0,ngrid/2
419         do ifold=0,nfoldpow-1
420            write(lunit,'(I,$)') waven(k,ifold)
421         enddo
422         write(lunit,'(I)') waven(k,nfoldpow)
423      enddo
424      close(lunit)
```

How can I compile this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing the format string `I` to `Iw` where `w` is a positive number. Same with `E`, only use `Ew.d`.
For explanation see, for example, this link:
http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap05/format.html

Beware though: using, say, `I3` for writing out 1234 might print `***`, so make sure your formats are wide enough.

EDIT: See @M.S.B.'s answer on how to avoid problems with integer formats.

Answer (score 11):

As already answered, you need to specify widths.    Something like ES14.5 might work well for the floating point format.   There is a short cut for the integer format: I0 will cause the compiler to use the number of digits needed.

Comment: With gfortran, I wouldn't hesitate to use `g0` format for both.

Comment: @VladimirF, thanks for that suggestion! That ended up helping me out quite a bit with a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19503960/289099

Comment: @VladimirF do you think `g0` can help for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44860322/gfortran-requires-format-widths-while-ifort-doesnt ?? is `g0` a compiler option or something that must be included in the source code itself?

Comment: This program is using extensions - omitting widths for I and using the $ format (which suppresses a newline.)  G0 is standard Fortran 2003. It was extended to allow G0.d in F2008 and extended again to allow use with character values in F2018.