# gfortran - Is unspecified decimal length allowed for real output?

Tags: format, fortran, output, gfortran, real-datatype

Is there a way to format a real number for output such that both the width and decimal parts are left unspecified? This is possible with ifort by just doing the following:

`write (*, '(F)') num`

...but I understand that that usage is a compiler-specific extension. Gfortran does accept the standard-compliant 0-width specifier, but I can't find anything in the standard nor in gfortran's documentation about how to leave the decimal part unspecified. The obvious guess is to just use 0 for that as well, but that yields a different result. For example, given this:

```
real :: num
num = 3.14159
write (*, '(F0.0)') num
```

...the output is just `3.`. I know I could specify a decimal value greater than zero, but then I am liable to have undesired extra zeros printed.

What are my options? Do I have any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Best solution:**

It turns out that the easiest solution is to use the `g` specifier ("g" for "generalized editing"). That accepts a `0` to mean unspecified/processor-dependent width, which is exactly what I wanted. This is preferable to leaving the entire format unspecified (`write(*,*)`) because you can still control other parts of the output, for example:

```
real :: num
character(len=10) :: word
num = 3.14159
word = 'pi = '
write (*, '(a5,g0)') word, num
```

yields this:

```
pi = 3.14159012
```

Thanks to [Vladimir F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721644/vladimir-f) for the idea (seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11039553/289099)).

**Inferior alternative:**

My first thought this morning after seeing High Performance Mark's answer was to write the real number to a character string and then use that:

```
character(len=20) :: cnum
write (cnum, *), num
write (*, '(a5,a)') word, trim(adjustl(cnum))
```

It yields the same output as the best solution, but it is a little more complicated and it doesn't offer quite as much control, but it gets close.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use *list-directed output*, that is

```
write(*,*) num
```

but this surrenders all control of `num`'s format to the compiler which is allowed to choose any reasonable representation.

Your question makes clear some formatting options that you don't want, but is less forthcoming on a clear specification of how you want the output formatted.

Comment: You are correct, I failed to mention that I wanted to be able to write reals alongside other data in the same `write` statement. If I didn't need to do that, then your suggestion does do the job, although it offers minimal control of the output. However, your idea set me off to think of a few other things that did end up working well, so thanks for the inspiration!