# gfortran requires format widths while ifort doesn't?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to migrate a .FOR file (for practice purposes) from ifort to gfortran. This file compiles in my Intel Visual Fortran solution with no issues. However when I compile it in gfortran using the following command:

```
gfortran -ffree-form -ffree-line-length-200 -Dinternal_debug -c MyFile.FOR -o MyFile.o
```

I get the following error message:

```
MyFile.FOR:4561:22:

   102     format(A, I)
                      1
Error: Nonnegative width required in format string at (1)
```

Does ifort simply not require there to be a format width or are there additional ifort options that enable relaxing this requirement? How come the file runs smoothly in ifort but not in gfortran?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation is correct, I have encountered this myself before. Intel Fortran does not enforce this requirement while gfortran does. The field width is actually required by the Fortran standard. I am not aware of any compiler option that could change this behaviour. The only option I am aware of is to fix the code to make it standard compliant.

How to do it can be found in [Error: Nonnegative width required in format string at (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11037954/721644) . Note that the `g0` that you asked about is not a compiler option to accept `I`. It is a different format descriptor to put into the code instead of `I`.