# Have I understood the fortran FORMAT properly?

Tags: fortran, format, gfortran, fortran90

I am trying to compile someone else's code but am not use to fortran. When trying to compile I get the error

```
ForceToForce.f90:119.34:

     99 FORMAT(3(F15.10),X,3I)
                              1
Error: Nonnegative width required in format string at (1)
ForceToForce.f90:120.37:

     111 FORMAT(4(F15.10),X,2(3I))
                                 1
Error: Nonnegative width required in format string at (1)
ForceToForce.f90:153.60:

                       WRITE(399999,FMT=111)QPCOM(i,1),QPCOM(i
                                                        1
Error: FORMAT label 111 at (1) not defined
```

I did a bit of research and I understand that you need to put an integer after the I to gin the number of positions used. So I changed the line to

```
111 FORMAT(4(F15.10),X,2(I3))
```

and the code complies but gives me a segmentation fault. As this is the only thing I changed in I assume I must have misunderstood how FORMAT is suppose to be used. Is there something else I should try?

Comment: The format string you end up with looks fine.  Would you mind posting the full `WRITE` line where you use 111?  Perhaps what you are giving the `WRITE` statement is not matching the format 111.

Comment: Is this the right line? 

`WRITE(399999,FMT=111)QPCOM(i,1),QPCOM(i,2),QPCOM(i,3),&
                                        &real(-(1.0d0/sqrt(1.0d0*NSUB))*(cdotp(antalmod,W,F)/DBLE(QAMP(FOUM(i,l),j)))*(const2/(2.0d0*pi))**2),i,j`

Comment: Pleas always use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. I would have closed the question as a duplicate. I must write an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is wrong. `2(3I)` specifies six integers. `2(I3)` is two integers, each of them with a width of 3 characters.

The Fortran standard requires that a non-negative width is specified for the I edit descriptor as *clearly* stated in the error message. See [Error: Nonnegative width required in format string at (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037954/error-nonnegative-width-required-in-format-string-at-1/11039553#11039553) The code used to be probably compiled by Intel Fortran, which does not strictly enforce this restriction.

So, your solution is wrong. You can use `3I0` and you should be fine and the behaviour will likely remain exactly the same.

Comment: I see now thank you for your help

Comment: You mean `3I0`.